# I wanna join 2 tables in codeigniter but its not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

My code is

```
 function admin_profile()
{
 $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('bk_users as A');
    $this->db->join('bk_ctoe as B', 'A.ID=B.customer_id' );
    $this->db->join('bk_ctoe as C', 'A.ID=C.employee_id' );
return  $this->db->get()->result();
} 
 same as
  SELECT * FROM `bk_users` as `A` JOIN `bk_ctoe` as `B` ON 
    `A`.`ID`=`B`.`customer_id` JOIN `bk_ctoe` as `C` ON 
    `A`.`ID`=`C`.`employee_id`
```

This query return the empty columns. I'm also adding picture for a better understanding [image]  thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying the data is returned correctly with the raw SQL, but not when you build the query through Code Igniter? Otherwise it's not a CI question.

Comment: no am just saying this query return empty string in ci and when i use raq query in my db there returns empty coloums not the actual data i want to select

Comment: INNER JOIN requires to reference matches on both sides, make sure your data is there.

Comment: as seen in the picture your `customer_id` and `employee_id` is same as `id` from `bk_users`. Which does not make sense. make sure your `employee_id` and `customer_id` is correct.

Comment: my table users have all the users. in customer_id contain tha id of customer that is pressent in users same case with employee

Comment: What does the data look like in bk_ctoe? if a record has a customer_id, will employee_id be null and vice versa?

Comment: table bk_ctoe contains the id as foriegn key like if a user have id 6 and he is customer then in customer_id contain that id 6 of bk_users table

Comment: Please answer my question though. IF he has a customerid will employee id be null? this is important!

Comment: no its like which customer id assign to which employee like in bk_users id 6 is a customer and is assign to id7 who is a employee then in table bk_ctoe customer_id is 6 and employe_id is 7 means customer 6 assign to employe 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  function admin_profile()
{
    $this->db->select('B.FNAME as customer,B.email,B.contact, C.FNAME AS 
    employee,B.active as active_user,A.active as assigned');
    $this->db->from('bk_ctoe as A');
    $this->db->join('bk_users B', 'B.ID=A.customer_id' );
    $this->db->join('bk_users C', 'C.ID=A.employee_id' );
return  $this->db->get()->result();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code in CI change your method like below. This will return matching id with either `customer_id` or `employee_id`

```
function admin_profile()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('bk_users as A');
    $this->db->join('bk_ctoe as B', 'A.ID=B.customer_id OR A.ID=B.employee_id' );    
    return  $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code as an example,

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('login');
    $this->db->join('registration', 'registration.userid = login.userid');
    //$query=$this->db->get('registration');
    $this->db->where('login.status',2);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query;
```

Comment: i have done and post the answer. Thanks for your help. its so nice of you